# Drools7.5 High memory Issue

Tags: jvm, drools

Drools7.5 Stateful Session, when I fire 20 rules and 80 thousand objects,
the jvm used 16G memory.
I have tried to modify the jvm memory to 32G, memory alse been used.
How does it happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please capture heap dump and see which objects are consuming more memory. Also it will be great if you can share reproducer with us.